# how to upload asp.net website on my hosting server

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have created a website in visual studio 2010. But there is no option to publish the site. It is available when I create a web application but not with a website. Now I need to host this on my hosting server. The connection string too needs to be changed. Plz advise on all this.

Comment: Are you using IIS to host your site? I mean who is hosting your site?

Comment: these are basic questions and already had lots of answer on net, please search on google

Comment: My google search has brought me here. Everybody is a beginner at some time. If the question has been answered here in the forum, maybe you could share your experience and link to it.